# How to insert todays date automatically?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to insert today's date in the following code automatically.

```
  import shutil
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\KUNDAN\Desktop\Backup\Cash MAR.2017 TO APR.2019.accdb",
                r"F:\Cash MAR.2017 TO APR.2019 (11-09-19).accdb ")
    print("DONE !!!")
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'm not 100% sure of your question.  If this doesn't answer it as you're expecting, please reformat your question to add clarity.

You can do this via the `datetime` library and string formatting.  For example (using UK date format):

```
import shutil 
from datetime import datetime as dt

today = dt.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y')
src = "C:/Users/KUNDAN/Desktop/Backup/Cash MAR.2017 TO APR.2019.accdb"
dst = "F:/Cash MAR.2017 TO APR.2019 ({today}).accdb".format(today=today)
shutil.copy(src, dst)
print("DONE !!!")
```

I have found these two links very useful:

- [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/)
- [datetime formatting using `strftime`](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
datetime_now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(datetime_now)
```

It will print the date and time for now and you can choose what format you like.